# Should I use signal/slot as much as I can in Qt?

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qt5, c++17

From [Qt documentation on Performance Considerations And Suggestions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html) I got the following:

```
use asynchronous, event-driven programming wherever possible
```

I'm not sure what that means, so would like to ask. Does it mean I should use signal/slots whenever possible (because they are asynchronous?)?

Comment: Yes, you should use signals and slots or similar elements as much as possible.

Comment: Even without having used `Qt`: Yes - `Qt` is supposed to be kind of portable and by using the framework supplied by `Qt`, you should be able to compile and run your program on any of the platforms `Qt` is targeting. If you start stepping out of it, be sure that you do it in a platform independent way.

Comment: Signals and slots are great to decouple classes (sender doesn’t need to know receiver), for asynchronous programming (notify listeners that some operation completed), and for cross-thread message passing-style communication. It doesn’t mean that every normal method call should be replaced by signal/slots, that would just result in worse readability and additional overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Qt signals/slots are not necessarily asynchronous. From https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html:

> Direct Connection: The slot is invoked immediately, when the signal is emitted. The slot is executed in the emitter's thread, which is not necessarily the receiver's thread.
>
> Queued Connection: The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.
>
> Blocking Queued Connection: The slot is invoked as for the Queued Connection, except the current thread blocks until the slot returns.

A signal subscribed to by a slot with a Direct Connection will be essentially a method call that you can "hook up" at runtime.

Also, yes, you should probably use "asynchronous, event-driven programming" "whenever possible" for a sane definition of "whenever possible".

Obviously, don't replace all method calls between your objects with signals and slots. And when you do use signals and slots, don't always make them asynchronous (Queued) - sometimes you will want the objects subscribed to your signals to finish their "reactions" to your signals before the emitting function proceeds.

In general, when you don't really care if the subscribers of your signals get their slots invoked immedtiatelly or later, just connect them up without specifying a connection type, and Qt will use Auto Connection, which will do the right thing (thread-wise). When you do care, just specify the type of connection you want.

If you feel confused by this at first, a reasonable thing to do might also be to make all connections Queued by default - you won't really notice any performance difference, and this might prevent you from accidentally writing code that depends on the slots executing "directly", when that was not your intent.

The suggestion in your link is mainly meant for any events that get generated on your main thread, most likely by UI elements - buttons, etc. The main idea is that you want to process any input events as quickly as possible, to keep the main thread free for accepting any later events and rendering your UI, and, if the events cause any significant work to be done, move that work to another thread, and have your main thread wait for a completion signal, so that your main thread remains "responsive". If you want your UI to immedtially react to any events, for example, by initiating a "loading spinner" or displaying a progress bar, you can, of course, do that directly. This, of course, also applies to any other threads that might need to remain responsive and handle other events while a larger calculation is happening in the background.

Comment: But when calling a slot we do this business in the event loop right? A direct method call isn't faster? I mean in a context where method needs to be called multiple times per second, let's say 5 times per second.

Comment: A direct method call is faster. Integer addition is also faster than integer division, but if you only do it 5 times a second, you will not be able to measure the difference.